# Vsftpd permission users

Tags: 14.04

I have something I do not understand very well .
My Ubuntu machine name is admin @ Ubuntu
When I send administrator username and password mypassword have permissions to anything in the FTP server .
How can I decide which user gets some kind of privilege ? ?

In addition , I checked the file vsftpd.conf and the ftpusers file in the folder ETC.
But I found nothing related to permissions !

Answer (score 0):

Most Ubuntu ftpd's use Linux own right management this means you have to set the privileges via `chown` and `chmod`